# RabbitMQ - Get total count of messages enqueued

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I have a Java client which monitors RabbitMQ queue. I am able to get the count of messages currently in queue with this code

```
@Resource
RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin;
..........

DeclareOk declareOk = rabbitAdmin.getRabbitTemplate().execute(new ChannelCallback<DeclareOk>() {
        public DeclareOk doInRabbit(Channel channel) throws Exception {
            return channel.queueDeclarePassive("test.pending");
        }
    });
     return declareOk.getMessageCount();
```

I want to get some more additional details like  -

1. Message body of currently enqueued items.
2. Total number of messages that was enqueued in the queue since the queue was created.

Is there any way to retrieve these data in Java client?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

With AMQP protocol (including RabbitMQ implementation) you can't get such info with 100% guarantee.

The closest number to messages count is messages count returned with `queue.declare-ok` ([`AMQP.Queue.DeclareOk`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v3.5.6/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-3.5.6/com/rabbitmq/client/AMQP.Queue.DeclareOk.html) in java AMQP client library).

Whilst messages count you receive with `queue.declare-ok` may match exact messages number enqueues, you can't rely on it as it doesn't count messages which waiting acknowledges or published to queue during transaction but not committed yet.

It really depends what kind of precission do you need.

As to enqueued messages body, you may want to manually extract all messages in queue, view their body and put them back to queue. This is the only way to do what you want.

You can get some information about messages count with [Management Plugin](http://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html), [RabbitMQ Management HTTP API](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/3646dee55e02/priv/www-api/help.html) and [rabbitmqctl](http://www.rabbitmq.com/man/rabbitmqctl.1.man.html) util (see list_queues, list_channels).

You can't get total published messages count since queue was created and I think nobody implement such stats while it useless (FYI, with messages flow in average 10k per second you will not even reach uint64 in a few thousand years).

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted to confirm if there is any API to support these since I couldn't find it documented anywhere.

Comment: A small correction to what zaq178miami wrote: 10k messages per second for 2 weeks is a total of 1,463,132,160,000 messages. An unsigned int 64 bit is 2^64 = 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 far more than that.

Comment: Note If you google for "RabbitMQ Management HTTP Stats", you'll see that there is a "publish" counter that is the queue's total nb of enqueued messages (since the broker was started as far as I could notice). Also note that setting msg_rates_age and msg_rates_incr querystring parameters will provide historized values of such counter.

Answer (score 15):

```
AMQP.Queue.DeclareOk dok = channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, queueArgs);
dok.getMessageCount();
```

Comment: is there any such code to get all the names of the queues currently in the broker???

Comment: You'll get an error if queue declaration args are different from those queue was created with. Use queueDeclarePassive instead

Answer (score 10):

To access queue details via http api,

`http://public-domain-name:15672/api/queues/%2f/queue_name`

To access queue details via command from localhost cli promt,

`curl -i -u guest_uname:guest_password http://localhost:15672/api/queues/%2f/queue_name`

Where,
'%2f' is default vhost `/`. (%2f URL encoding of `/` character)

[NOTE - As mentioned in comment, management plugin needs to be enabled.]

Comment: It should be noted that this solution depends on the Management Plugin. https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#http-api-endpoints

Comment: I must be the only one on earth who wonders why the `%2f` is there.

Comment: Added (%2f URL encoding of / character) to answer.  You can check here, https://www.urlencoder.org