# Get total messages count in RabbitMQ

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, message-queue

I need to know the total messages in RabbitMQ from .NET client. I know the best solution is using API HTTP but I doesn't work properly.

I use confirmation of published messages, but I don't know why it doesn't work.

I use this code in order to publish a message in RabbitMQ:

```
private void message(string text)
{
    var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = hostName, UserName = user, Password = password };
    using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
    using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
    {
        try
        {

            channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchangeNameProducer, "direct", true);
            channel.QueueDeclare(queueNameProducer, true, false, false, null);
            channel.ConfirmSelect();
            channel.QueueBind(queueNameProducer, exchangeNameProducer, "");
            var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
            channel.BasicPublish(exchangeNameProducer, "", null, body);
            channel.WaitForConfirmsOrDie();
            log("After WaitForConfirm ,messageCount = " + this.getMessagesCount() + " ; message = " + text);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

"getMessagesCount" function asks to HTTP API to know total message count. Notice I use WaitForConfirmsOrDie and ConfirmSelect functions in order to wait until the message is published.

In my example, the consumer takes 30 seconds processing the message.
However, the log always prints 0 messages remaining, but If I debug the code, the log prints 1 message remaining. If I use this code (waiting 1 second after publishing the message):

```
channel.BasicPublish(exchangeNameProducer, "", null, body);
channel.WaitForConfirmsOrDie();
Thread.Sleep(1000);
log("After WaitForConfirm ,messageCount = " + this.getMessagesCount() + " ; message = " + text);
```

then it works properly and the log writes "1 message left"

I think RabbitMQ lasts a few seconds to update message count from HTTP API, or it doesn't wait in WaitForConfirmsOrDie function.

Could you help me please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you need to get messages count in specific queue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684848/rabbitmq-get-total-count-of-messages-enqueued, else there are not other way rather than calling HTTP API (or running cli tool).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the statistics interval in the management plugin: https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#statistics-interval

By default the DB is updated every 5 seconds, but you can configure that. Keep in mind that performance will be affected if you reduce that value, since more writes will be performed by the management DB