# rabbitmq - the queue appears to be empty even though there are messages on it

Tags: php, rabbitmq, queue, message-queue

I have a rabbit consumer that works fine (it correctly processes messages, sends acks, etc.).

In it, I am trying to check if a queue is empty using the queue_declare and passive flag (as suggested here: [RabbitMQ - How to check if queue is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32460212/rabbitmq-how-to-check-if-queue-is-empty)).

The relevant part of the code looks like this:

```
  <?php
      $a = $this->channel->queue_declare($queueName, true);
      var_dump($a);
```

My problem is that it always returns (regardless on how many messages are on queue - I tested with like 1000):

```
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
        string(4) "fastQueue"
      [1]=>
        int(0)
      [2]=>
        int(1)
    }
```

Any idea why?

Comment: What PHP library are you using? What version of RabbitMQ and Erlang? Could you provide a complete set of code to reproduce?

Comment: Typically the size of a queue is not relevant to the consumers of the queue - this indicates poor system design. However, there is a management API which can be used to return queue size, if that is indeed what you are looking for.

Comment: @LukeBakken I'm using lates RabbitMQ, https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib as lib and... I'll get back to you with Erlang version (I am on phone atm).

Comment: @theMayer I don't really care about the size of the queue, I just care if is empty or not because I don't wanna keep the connection open if there is nothing on queues (if you can explain why this would be poor system design I would appreciate it). Also in the future I actually was thinking to check queue size and spawn additional consumers / raise processes priorities for spikes (again, why would that be poor system design - no sarcasm, I'm genuinely asking).

Comment: `Basic.Get` is what you’re looking for. It returns immediately whether there is a message available or not.