# Is there a way to determine the number of messages before a specific message with RabbitMQ to provide "N messages before yours" counter?

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue

I would like to give feedback to users (message issuers) when their messages will be processed (not when they are done).

Theoretically I could receive all the messages, count and reschedule them. This would be stupid due to new arriving messages would be processed immediately due to all the message before the new messages would be rescheduled after the new (initial last) messages.

Is there a way to determine the number of messages before a specific message with RabbitMQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid there is currently no way on the server side to find the number of messages published before a particular message though rabbitmq provides an [HTTP API](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/3646dee55e02/priv/www-api/help.html) which returns the number of messages currently in the queue.

You will have to maintain this statistic on the client side(like a counter or something) preferably at the publisher end. But make sure to publish the message only once in order to avoid duplicate counts or implement your counter in a such a way(keep a unique identifier per message) so as to avoid counting the same message more than once (if republishing is allowed).

A similar question has been asked before :
[RabbitMQ - Get total count of messages enqueued](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684848/rabbitmq-get-total-count-of-messages-enqueued)

Comment: Just came across this link: http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/9b44a7aca551/priv/www/doc/stats.html

Have a look if this helps.