# How can I create Progress for Springboot + Rabbit MQ?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

I have tried creating progress with updating field as counter in database, but I have trouble since I use two and more machine with parallel process. That make database not counting in right direction. How can create right counter for every data in Queue has been process.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [RabbitMQ - Get total count of messages enqueued](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684848/rabbitmq-get-total-count-of-messages-enqueued)

This describes how you get the number of messages in the queue. With that number you should be able to calculate a progress (if you know how much entries were added to the queue in the first place)

```
private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "hello";

public static void main(String[] argv) throws java.io.IOException, InterruptedException, TimeoutException, KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost("localhost");
    factory.setPort(5672);

    factory.setUsername("guest");
    factory.setPassword("guest");

    Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

    AMQP.Queue.DeclareOk declareOk = channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
    System.out.println(declareOk);

    channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, null, "Hello, world!".getBytes());

    declareOk = channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
    System.out.println(declareOk);

    System.out.println(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");
}
```

The output is:

```
#method<queue.declare-ok>(queue=hello, message-count=1, consumer-count=0)
#method<queue.declare-ok>(queue=hello, message-count=2, consumer-count=0)
[*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C
```

I'm using RabbitMq 3.6.9 and as you see, this works fine.

Comment: Well unfortunately i have read that but when i tried excute this `declareOk.getMessageCount()` always get zero count also hop `Client rabbitRestApi = new Client("http://127.0.0.1:15672/api/", "guest", "guest");` give me null am i doing it wrong ?