# RabbitMq Java - Get Channel for Queue to detect if there are unhandled messages

Tags: java, rabbitmq

We're using RabbitMq for communication between some of our services. Sometimes there are a lot of messages beeing queued at once. We want to be able to see that there are still unhandled messages, i.e. if the Service handling the messages is busy.

I've been looking around for a programmatical way to check if a queue has messages and found this

```
channel.queueDeclarePassive(queueName).getMessageCount()
```

The problem is: I dont have a channel object. Our RabbitMq setup has been created a couple of years ago and usually looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
public class RabbitMqConfig {

  public static final String RENDER_HTML_QUEUE = "render.html";

  private String rabbitUri;

  private int connectionTimeout;

  private String exchangeName;

  private int concurrentConsumers;

  public RabbitMqConfig(
      @Value("${rabbitmq.uri}") String rabbitUri,
      @Value("${rabbitmq.exchange.name}") String exchangeName,
      @Value("${rabbitmq.connection.timeout}") int timeout,
      @Value("${rabbitmq.concurrent-consumers:1}") int concurrentConsumers) {
    this.exchangeName = exchangeName;
    this.rabbitUri = rabbitUri;
    this.connectionTimeout = timeout;
    this.concurrentConsumers = concurrentConsumers;
  }

  @Bean
  DirectExchange directExchangeBean() {
    return new DirectExchange(this.exchangeName, true, false);
  }

  @Bean
  SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setQueueNames(RENDER_HTML_QUEUE);
    container.setConcurrentConsumers(concurrentConsumers);
    container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
    return container;
  }

  @Bean
  MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(RenderItemMessageConsumer receiver) {
    return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "reciveMessageFromRenderQueue");
  }

  @Bean
  public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    try {
      connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(new URI(this.rabbitUri));
      connectionFactory.setConnectionTimeout(this.connectionTimeout);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
      throw new ApiException(e, BaseErrorCode.UNKOWN_ERROR, e.getMessage());
    }
    return connectionFactory;
  }

  @Bean
  public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {
    return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory());
  }
  @Bean
  public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
    return new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
  }

  @Bean
  public Queue renderRenderQueue() {
    return new Queue(RENDER_HTML_QUEUE, true);
  }

  @Bean
  Binding rendererRenderBinding() {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(renderRenderQueue()).to(directExchangeBean()).with(
        RENDER_HTML_QUEUE);
  }

}
```

Messages are then consumed like this:

```
@Component
public class RenderItemMessageConsumer {
  @RabbitListener(queues = RENDER_HTML_QUEUE)
  public void reciveMessageFromRenderQueue(String message) {
    //...
  }
```

The exchangeName is shared across services. So generally I need a way to get the channel that probably is created for the queue and connection to see how many messages are inside. Ideally I want to access that information at the other service that produces the messages consumed in the rendering service.

Or am I doing something wrong? Do I have to explicitly create a channel and connect the queue to it? I'm not even sure what channels are created under the hood, as I mentioned I've set this up some years ago and didnt dig deeper after everything was running fine.

Can I maybe somehow use the amqpAdmin to get all channels?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684848/rabbitmq-get-total-count-of-messages-enqueued

Comment: Yeah, this might have helped had I stumbled accross it before answering my own question ;) But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I can answer my own question after just a little more trying around:

```
  @Autowired
  private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

  public Boolean isBusy(String queue) throws IOException {
    Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel(false);
    return channel.queueDeclarePassive(queue).getMessageCount() > 0;
  }
```

Since all my services have a similar setup exposing the connectionFactory as a bean and they all connect to the shared rabbitMq server using the same exchange name, I can just use any service to do the above. I can put that snippet behind a rest resource and thus from my management UI can request all the information about the queues of which I know the names to decide if I want to post another batch of messages to it.